# I want to create a HashMap out of two arrays that I have (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

Right now my program is outputing the data I would like it to (I checked it with some system.out.println statements) but I want to convert the two arrays into a hashmap that includes both.  I do not know how to do that. Please help!

Here is the code I have:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Vending2 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
      System.out.print("Enter your food selection file: ");      // User inputs file
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);                       // Keyboard input from user
      String filename = input.nextLine();
      Scanner fs = new Scanner(new File(filename));         // Scans in the file that was inputed

        String line;
        double price;
        int num = 0;
        while(fs.hasNextLine()){
             line = fs.nextLine();
             price = Double.parseDouble(line.split(":")[0]);
             num++;
        }

        fs.close();
        fs = new Scanner(new File(filename));

        double[] value = new double[num];                        //Array for prices
        int i = 0;
        while(fs.hasNextLine()){
             line = fs.nextLine();
             price = Double.parseDouble(line.split(":")[0]);
             value[i] = price;
             i++;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(value));

        fs.close();
        fs = new Scanner(new File(filename));

         ArrayList<String> foods = new ArrayList<String>();  
        while( fs.hasNext()){

            String str = fs.nextLine();
            String words[] = str.split(":");
            if (words.length > 0){

                for(int j=1; j < words.length; j++){
                    foods.add(words[j]);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("foods="+foods);


    }
  }
```

And here is what it is outputing so far (this is what I want to put into a hashmap) :

```
1.0, 1.5, 1.5, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.25, 0.75, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 1.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 3.5, 1.75, 0.25, 1.5]
foods=[Honey roasted peanuts, Cheetos, Bugles, Synder’s Pretzels, Snickers, Twix, M n Ms, Life savers, Twizzlers, Nutter Butters, Butter Fingers, King Size Kit Kats, Carrot sticks, Juicy Fruit, Spearmint Gum, Five gum, Pepperoni, Cheez-Its, Slim Jim, Lays Barbeque Chips]
```

Comment: So you want to map food names into respective prices?

Comment: Your current history of questions gives the (*strong*) impression that you are using stackoverflow as a "homework-making-machine". However, a question like this one *may* be legitimate, and if you tried to phrase it in a form that is more appropriate for a Q/A site, then they would likely be percieved better. This refers to details of the wording ("I want to" vs. "How to"), but also to focussing on the *core* of the question: No `Scanners`, no files, just a `main` method with two hard-coded arrays. Also, you should be *precise* about which array contains *keys* and which one contains *values*

Comment: It would be best if you mapped them straight out of the file. Can you add a sample from the file to your question?

Comment: @RealSkeptic See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219776/scanning-a-txt-file-and-creating-an-array-out-of-strings-in-this-case-vending ... ... ...

Comment: @Marco13 Interesting. Then I wonder how `split(":")` would work at all... I suppose your previous comment makes sense.

Comment: @Marc13 not for homework..... trying to learn java and I am super new at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming both `foods` list and `value` array are always of the same length, so you can loop over them together.

```
Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String, Double>();

int i = 0;
while (i < foods.size() && i < value.length) { //for safety i will check on both sizes
    map.put(foods.get(i), value[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your answer? Code-only answers are frowned upon on SO.

Answer (score 1):

If your two arrays/list have same length, just do :

```
Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    map.put(foods[i], value[i]);
    // or map.put(foods.get(i), value[i]) if foods is a List
}
```

Assuming there is only one price for one food.

Comment: How do I implement this into my given code? where do I put it without saying that "i" has already been defined. (Sorry I am VERY new to java)

Comment: Just rename the variable into `j`. Also, you probably need a `Map<String, Double> if your prices are not integers.

Comment: Ok I did that and it says "array required".

Comment: You need `foods.get(j)` because it's a list, not an array.

Comment: Thank you, but then it says "cannot find method "foods(int)""

Comment: foods(j) means you are passing j to foods. foods[j] means you are accessing the jth index from foods